# What's the behaviour of `File::poll_write()`?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio

I'm referring to this method in particular: https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/io/trait.AsyncWrite.html#tymethod.poll_write. If I understand future's correctly, this `poll` method gets executed by an executor in two possible ways: on the first `.await` invocation or when the task's `Waker` is signaled.

If this is true, then I'm confused by the function's api:

```
fn poll_write(
        self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_>,
        buf: &[u8],
    ) -> Poll<Result<usize, io::Error>>;
```

When I first call `poll_write`, I understand that I would need to pass in the `buf` of bytes. However, when the Future gets woken up again and the poll function is re-invoked what happens to the `buf`? Is it discarded?

Consider this example:

```
struct MyWriter {
   file: File,
   my_val: i32
}

impl MyWriter {
   fn new(file: File) -> Self {
      Self {
         file,
         my_val: 0
      }
   }

   fn get_val(&mut self) -> i32 {
      let old = self.my_val;
      self.my_val += 1;
      old
   }
}

impl Future for MyWriter {
    type Output = i32;

    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        // Invoke some additional logic
        let _ = self.my_logic();
        let bytes = vec![];
        bytes.append(self.get_val());
        

        match self.file.poll_write(cx, bytes) {
           Poll::Ready(_) => Poll::Ready(0),
           _ => Poll::Pending
        }
    }
}

// What's the behaviour of the following?
let writer = MyWriter { file };
let ans = writer.await;
```

If on the first poll the `poll_write` is not ready then the process is yielded. Eventually, the context waker is awakened; does this mean that the `self.my_logic()` is called again? Since this is a 'wakened-up' state, then what does the `self.file.poll_write(cx, bytes)` do now? Does it just return a `Poll::Ready(_)`? Does it just 'know' that since it was re-wakened, it can just disregard the `bytes`?

---

Edit:

Appended the `my_val` field to the writer struct.

On the first run of `poll`, `self.get_val()` returns zero so we try to write `0` into the file. Let's say that the write is not ready so we return pending.

Eventually, the waker is signalled so `poll` is called again. This time, `self.get_val()` returns 1. What happens now? Does `poll_write()` now try to write `1` into the file? Or does it discard this write and just yield the `Poll::Ready(_)` from the last write of `0`?

Comment: The source is open, you can read the implementation: https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/src/tokio/fs/file.rs.html#626

Answer (score 0):

> However, when the Future gets woken up again and the poll function is re-invoked what happens to the `buf`? Is it discarded?

Quite the opposite. Only the last `buf` is used - then the file is ready for write; all previous `buf`s are discarded. [This is specified in the documentation](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/io/trait.AsyncWrite.html):

> - `Poll::Pending` means that no data was written from the buffer provided. The I/O object is not currently writable but may become writable in the future. Most importantly, **the current future’s task is scheduled to get unparked when the object is writable**.

> does this mean that the `self.my_logic()` is called again?

`MyWriter::poll()` will be called again, and so yes, `my_logic()` will also be called again.

> Does it just return a `Poll::Ready(_)`?

By the documentation I cited above, it immediately writes the bytes and return `Poll::Ready`. However, as far as I know futures may be woken spuriously, so you should not rely on that (I may be wrong, though, I'm not sure).

Comment: I'm confused still, can you see my edit on the post? It sounds like what you're saying is that when the write is ready, it just writes the last request made. Does this mean that it's possible for me to 'lose' the original write request?

Comment: @Kiwibreeder When the write is ready, it'll write whatever data you give to it. So it will write 1.